# Is it possible to remotely delete cookies in frontEnd of app?

Tags: spring, cookies, spring-security, session-cookies

I'm working on remote logging out from my app based on a API call provided from other app.
Normally when user is logging out using my app I use Spring .logout().deleteCookies().

Now that we use one authorization server for many apps, we need to ensure that logging out from one will logout other apps as well.

So the basic idea is that the authorization server will call my API let's say /user/logout
And when I get this call I would like the same thing as spring .logout().deleteCookies() does. How can I achieve that?

Is it possible to just add the new API to Spring configuration? Say change this config:

```
.logout()
.logoutUrl(logoutUrl)
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
.clearAuthentication(true)
.logoutSuccessUrl("/")
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
```

to something like :

```
.logout()
.logoutUrl(logoutUrl || 'api/user/logout)
.invalidateHttpSession(true)
.clearAuthentication(true)
.logoutSuccessUrl("/")
.deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
```

?

My whole spring configuration is :

```
http
                        .addFilterBefore(new RedirectUrlFilter(projectDomainPath), OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter.class)
                        .csrf().disable().cors()
                        .and()
                        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                        .and()
                        .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/static/**", "/logout", "/api/user/k_push_not_before", "/api/user/k_logout").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                        .and()
                        .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), secret, clientId, "nblues", tokenVerificationUrl))
                        .logout()
                        .logoutUrl(logoutUrl)
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/api/user/k_push_not_before"))
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                        .clearAuthentication(true)
                        .logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                        .and()
                        .oauth2Login()
                        .loginPage(DEFAULT_AUTHORIZATION_REQUEST_BASE_URI + "/" + realm);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try maybe something like this

```
.logout().permitAll()
         .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
         .invalidateHttpSession(true)
         .clearAuthentication(true)
         .logoutUrl("/logout")
         .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
```

and even add `.logoutSuccessHandler(new CustomLogoutSuccessHandler())`

that could look something like this

```
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler{
    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
                                Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() != null) {
            try {
                httpServletRequest.getSession().invalidate();
                System.out.println("User Successfully Logout");
                //you can add more codes here when the user successfully logs out,
                //such as updating the database for last active.
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
 
        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it works in Postman  got some weird error looking like html page, and I'm still logged into my app

Comment: Not sure for all your configuration, but you maybe need to add some annotation in your security configuration class as @EnableSpringHttpSession or @EnableJdbcHttpSession and add ` @Bean
    public HttpSessionIdResolver httpSessionIdResolver() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionIdResolver("X-Auth-Token");
    }`

Comment: Actually when I've added this succes handler now the problem is my auth is null. So the code in try block is never called. Even when I trie yo do authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(); it's still null when I'm calling from Postman, beeing logged into the app in my browser at the same time

Comment: Maybe to post your security configuration class so someone will see where problem could be

Comment: I;ve posted my whole configure (HttpSecurity http) method

Comment: Check this out maybe this help https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1537